# Cómo se calculan los "bits de entropía" de este cómic?

Tags: seguridad, contraseña

[Este cómic de xkcd](https://xkcd.com/936/) apareció el otro día impreso por la oficina.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Recuerdo [una entrevista (de John Oliver) a Edward Snowden](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yzGzB-yYKcc) que este último recomineda cambiar la mentalidad de "passwords" a "passphrases" y propone "margaretthacheris110%SEXY" como una *buena* contraseña.

Tras ver la tira cómica el otro día ando un poco confundido acerca de cuánto aportan los caracteres "especiales" o el uso de mayúsculas y minúsculas a una contraseña. En ese cómic, cómo se calculan esos "bits de entropía" que indican que una contraseña es más difícil de romper por fuerza bruta que la otra?

Comment: [Aquí](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/936:_Password_Strength) hay una interesante explicación

Comment: existe una wiki para explicar xkcd?!

Comment: gracias a este, https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/923, al fin entendi el titulo de esta medalla, https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/12/strunk-white,

Comment: @JorgeArturoJuarez y como es algo desconocido para los hispanohablantes, propuse en Meta [Cambiemos el nombre de la medalla “Strunk & White” por algo más reconocible](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2077/83).